# Spring oauth2 token based authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have two queries regarding spring oauth2 -

1) With client crendentials grant type, as part of /oauth/token call, is it possible to validate client id and secret via a remote service call rather than maintaining the client credentials in DB or in memory as the client credentials are maintained in a remote system? If client credentials are maintained in a remote system, can the tokens still be maintained in the my app (in memory or db)?

2) While building a REST back end for mobile/native apps, what kind of grant type should be used so as to be able to generate a unique token for each logged in user such that one logged in user cannot use the token generated for another logged in user?

Regards,
Jacob

Comment: For question 2, you can refer to this. https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/ .
The flow chart let you know what grant type to use based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to address question 2: Use `password` and `refresh_token` grants. [See](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/spring-boot-building-api-backend/blob/master/chapter05/02%20-%20Oauth%20configurable/src/main/java/com/example/copsboot/infrastructure/security/OAuth2ServerConfiguration.java#L80)  for an example configuration.

If you want an in-depth explanation of it, see [Practical Guide to Building an API Back End with Spring Boot](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/spring-boot-building-api-backend/) (Disclaimer: I am the author)

Comment: Thanks Wim. based on the code it seems the front end app will need to pass client id and secret to use password grant. That would mean the app needs to store it locally which may be a security risk. Also with password grant, can a token issued for one user same client be used by another user for the same client (since client id is same)?

Comment: To know what user is calling your REST api, you need to use the `@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal` argument to your controller method. The `principal` will have a reference to the user.